# Code coverage with dotCover in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, code-coverage, dotcover

My company got ReSharper licenses, so I'm trying out ReSharper's dotCover tool for code coverage. I've got the extension installed, it's up to date (2016.3.1), and my I'm using it in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

The Unit Test Explorer window finds all my tests, but when I run them and check the code coverage in the Unit Test Sessions window it shows me coverage for my test project and not the project under test.

It seems a lot like [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16144592/1680677) and a bit like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34952149/1680677), but neither helps. Has anyone else encountered this? Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or settings I need to change?

Comment: If you're using Resharper, why not use Unit Test Sessions window?

Comment: @PeterRitchie Running the tests from the Unit Text Explorer window pops up the results in the Unit Test Sessions window. I'll clarify that in the question.

Comment: ah, okay.  I use Resharper/Unit Tests/Cover All Tests from Solution and haven't had a problem.